# How to restrict users to only type English in Django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have a model form with field (forms.textinput) and i want users just can type english in this field and if they want type with another language get a error
thank you

Comment: how should i do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, if you would want to restrict the character set used just check if every char is element of [`strings.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html), maybe even add punctuation.
Semantically there is no trivial way known to me by default, also the idea may be oversimplified by you.

Comment: If we go down that road, I believe `string.printable` will be the best bet as it includes all punctuation, lower and upper case ascii letters and digits (and I believe it does so regardless of the used locale).